# Data passed to HomeComponent via router-outlet not rendering even though I can read the data in the console

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

I am new to Angular and trying to build a notes-app with routing but I've run into an issue I can't figure out:

I can get my `AddComponent` to load properly via `routerLink`, and then use `DataService` to pass the form-data from `AddComponent` to `HomeComponent` where I want to render the notes.  However, my `HomeComponent` will not render the list of notes even though I can read it when I console.log the notes in the `HomeComponent`.  The only way I can get it to work is by adding the `<app-home></app-home>` selector in my app.component.html but obviously this defeats the purpose of using the router and `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

Like I said, I am brand new to Angular and have spent hours reading thru documentation trying to figure out what the issues is so I would greatly appreciate any help!

Repo: https://github.com/iamcharliekim/angular-notes

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe, you don’t get only 1 note, you get all of them. The method `push()` you use when you want to add one element to an array. In your case you should change `this.notes.push(note)` into `this.notes = note`. But I would also change the name of the variable in subscribe to “notes” instead of “note” as there are many of them.

Comment: not sure if i understand exactly what you are saying but i tried your suggestion and it didn't work.  if i were to set this.notes.push(note) to this.notes = note, then it would only render the latest note that i submit.  i want to hold an array of notes objects in my HomeComponent and then iterate over it in my template using *ngFor.